# Display returned JSON array after POST DIV formatting incorrect

Tags: php, json, ajax, dom

Currently I am posting using AJAX to a PHP page (that executes SQL commands and returns a JSON Array `echo json_encode($runQueryArray);`).

I am having trouble using `$('#updateDisplay').append('');` to actually append the data correctly. It seems to be eating DIV styling and displaying out of order.

This is the returned JSON array:

```
[  
 {  
  "UserID":"1",
  "FirstName":"abc",
  "LastName":"xyz",
  "Email":"example@domain.com",
  "Username":"abc123",
  "Password":"badexample",
  "Deleted":"0",
  "DateCreated":"2017-08-13 13:06:44"
 }
]
```

I am trying to style it in this loop targeting the `<div id="updateDisplay">`

```
$("#updateDisplay").empty();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    context: document.body,
    data:{userid: myjavascriptfile.user.userID},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(JSON){
        $.each(JSON,function(i,val)
        {
            $('#updateDisplay').append('<div class="col-md-4"><!--image column--><img alt="User Profile Image" src="images/userProfile.png" class="img-circle"></div>');
            $('#updateDisplay').append('<div class="col-md-2"><!--empty spacer--></div>');
            $('#updateDisplay').append('<div class="col-md-6"><!--user content div-->');
                $('#updateDisplay').append('<dl class="dl-horizontal">');
                $('#updateDisplay').append('<h3 class="profileHeading">BIO</h3>');
                $('#updateDisplay').append('<dt><strong>Username: </strong></dt>');
                $('#updateDisplay').append('<dd>'+ val.Username + '</dd>');
                ...etc (one for each returned item)
            $('#updateDisplay').append('</div>');
```

Expected output return:

```
<div class="col-md-4"> <!--image column-->
    <img alt="User Profile Image" src="../images/userProfile.png" class="img-circle">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2"></div> <!--empty spacer-->
<div class="col-md-6"> <!--profile data column-->
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <h3 class="profileHeading">BIO</h3>
        <dt>
            <strong>Username: </strong>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            abc123
        </dd>
...etc (one for each returned item)
</div>
```

Current return:

```
<div class="col-md-6"><!--profile data column--></div>
<dt><strong>Username: </strong></dt>
<dd>abc123</dd>
```

If I place the ENTIRE append on one line of code it displays correctly but breaks when it is spread out across lines. e.g.

```
$('#updateDisplay').append('<div class="col-md-6"><!--profile data column--><dl class="dl-horizontal"><h3 class="profileHeading">BIO</h3><dt><strong>Username: </strong></dt><dd>'+ val.Username + '</dd><dt>');
```

Reading and making changes to something that long seems silly. There are no console errors. I tested the DIV styling without using an AJAX post using pre-filled dummy data and was able to get the desired output.

**Edit**

Solved following @Dimash comment I learnt about how to do multi line strings and only the one append. (Still very new sorry)

```
var profileData = "";
profileData = "<div class=\"col-md-4\"><img alt=\"User Profile Image\" src=\"images/userProfile.png\" class=\"img-circle\"></div>"
            + "<div class=\"col-md-2\"><!--empty spacer--></div>"
            + "<div class=\"col-md-6\"><!--profile data column-->"
            + "<dl class=\"dl-horizontal\">"
            + " <h3 class=\"profileHeading\">BIO</h3>"
            ...etc
            + "</div>";
            $('#updateDisplay').append(profileData);
```

Maybe next time a link to an example on how to do multi-line appends: [How to display a json array in table format? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45669437/display-returned-json-array-after-post-div-formatting-incorrect) Would better help people like myself understand what you meant by +=

Thanks for the guidance onto the right path!

Comment: `$('#updateDisplay').append('</div>');` - you can not append “partial elements” like this, that makes no sense. If you do not want to write this in one line, then break the parameter value into multiple lines. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append in right containers.

```
  $('#updateDisplay .col-md-6').append('<dl class="dl-horizontal"></div>');
  $('#updateDisplay .col-md-6 .profileHeading').append('<h3 class="profileHeading">BIO</h3>');
```

This will work.

But I recommend to do  one string  html += and append only once. But anyway, above will work.

NOTE
Append is not drawing, it appends html elements one after one, that fact that you are not closing tags - not helping

In your one line example you did not close container div, that's why it breaks.
Be more attentive please.

Comment: Thanks @Dimash, the one line example was stripped to preserve space and time, rather than listing all ~20 odd lines I would have to cram into the one line. Sorry if that was not clear in my example.